# Why text-shadow is visible even all parameters are set to 0

Tags: css

Why text-shadow css option is visible if color is specified but all other parameters are not.

For example:

```
//text-shadow: <color> <offset-x> <offset-y> <blur>
text-shadow: rgb(250, 190, 0) 0px 0px 0px
```

I don't understand why it's visible when offsets and blur are set to 0px
[image]

Comment: in all the browsers ?

Comment: Is it possibly inheriting CSS from somewhere?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried in both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having no blur does not make the shadow not be there, it just renders a solid shadow. The `blur` parameter doesn't make it *grow* by adding more pixels to this attribute, it's just not spread around an area.

As such, x and y offsets, or `h-shadow` and `v-shadow`, set to 0px will only set the shadow perfectly behind the text and will not hide it completely.

Read [this](https://www.crazyegg.com/blog/css3-text-shadow-effects/) for further reference, or check out [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp).